# NodeJS | Monk > Can not insert object into collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, monk

I am running into troubles with Monk for NodeJS. I have the following 2 files, an index.js (which I call with `node index.js`), and an utility file 'db'.

index.js

```
db = require('./../utilities/db');
var collection = db.get('collectionName');
collection.insert({});
process.exit();
```

db.js

```
const CONFIG    = require(__dirname + '/../../config/dev'),
  mongo         = require('mongodb'),
  monk          = require('monk'),
  db            = monk(CONFIG.mongodb.database);

module.exports = function(){
    return db;
}()
```

I have validated the value of CONFIG.mongodb.database to be mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db_name. When I run this code I expect that the collection 'collectionName' will be created with an empty document inside. But the collection is not created. What am I doing wrong here?

I am running a express webserver within the same codebase, this uses the same db file. But within this express server it IS working. I thought it had something to do with that, but shutting down my express server does not resolve the problem. Is there someone who knows where to look for a solution to this problem?

Comment: It's hard to tell with the code that you have shown, but my first guess is that it's a path error.  That `__dirname + '/../../config/dev'` does not point to the database you think it does.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am 100% sure that, that it is pointing to the correct database. For 2 reasons, I console.logged it and if it would be wrong I would see an other (wrong) database in my MongoDB.

Comment: But it is also good to note that do not get any errors when running this script

Comment: The previous code was correct, it was 1 simple line I forgot, which caused the problem `process.exit();`. Never-gonna make that mistake again! :')